# importing and starting example code in wicket userguide Wicket 8.x with netbeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, import, wicket, user-guide

I am totally new to wicket. So I am following the userguide and try to run the example code. ([wicket tutorial examples](https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-tutorial-examples))

I am running the code in Netbeans 8.2 on ubuntu linux and have maven installed. When I import the example code it is recognized as a maven project but somehow it is not recognized as a Wicket app. It cannot run the project, saying that it can't find the main method.

When I create a Maven project via [wicket quickstart](https://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) everything works fine, when I open the folder in Netbeans it is recognized as Wicket and when I run the project I can see the homepage of the app.

Can you help me? How can I make the examples from the Wicket userguide run from within Netbeans?

Martijn

Answer (score 1):

Just found the problem.In Netbeans I changed the packaging from 'jar' to 'war'

(on project right-click -> properties -> general -> Packaging)

Now I can run the project within Netbeans and see the app in the browser